# Same image slicing displays very different on 8 and 8 PLUS

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcasset

**Here's the** [Sample Project](https://github.com/tepmnthar/TestFuckingSlicedImage)

#### Problem

I want to make an image to have a fixed top half part and a stretched bottom half part which to make it properly resized in any height.

And I use image slicing in Assets.xcassets to achieve that. The image can be resized properly, however, it displays slightly different in different sizes.

#### The Original Image

[image: Screenshot 1]

#### Image Slicing

Just simply slice the image from the vertical center.

[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

#### Storyboard

**Content Mode** is set to **Scale to Fill**

Height constraint is equal to its width constraint multiplied by 0.8

[image: Screenshot 4]
[image: Screenshot 5]

#### Result

I think it should display nearly the same images in different devices. Because everything is the same except for the image assets(2x, 3x).

However, the result is not what I expect. The image seems a bit squashed on iPhone 8 PLUS.

[image: Screenshot 6]

#### At Last

I'm using Mojave with Xcode 10.1 (10B61).

Anyone knows what is the cause. And how to make the image vertically stretched properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it looks "squashed" is because the image is being stretched horizontally.

Your slicing allows the top portion to remain a constant height, but not a constant (or proportional) width.

Here, I use your original image *without* any slicing... each image view is the same height (201-pts), so you know it's not scaling vertically, but different widths so you can see the result of *horizontal* stretching:

[image]

What you may want to try is clipping your original image to only the top portion. Setup the constraints on that image view to stay proportional, and then use a solid color image view (or just a UIView with matching background color), as the lower "vertical stretch" section.